# find the number of Ring homorphism from $\mathbb{Z_2} \times \mathbb{Z_2}$ to $\mathbb{Z_4}$

Tags: abstract-algebra

find the number of Ring homorphism from  $\mathbb{Z_2} \times \mathbb{Z_2}$  to  $\mathbb{Z_4}$

My answer : one

let  $f$  be  a ring homorphism from   $\mathbb{Z_2} \times \mathbb{Z_2}$   to $\mathbb{Z_4}$

we know that $\mathbb{Z_2} \times \mathbb{Z_2}= K_4$ where $K_4$  is Klien Group

$K_4 = \{a^2 =b^2 =c^2 =e \  \text{and} \ c=ab\}$

There is only one idempotent element $e$ and there are $3$ nilpotent elements $a,b,c$ .

Now in  $\mathbb{Z_4} $ we have

$0^2=0,$

$1^2=1,$

$2^2=0,$

$3^2= 1$

so, $0$ and $1$ are idempotent  elements

we know that  in a ring Homomorphism idempotent map to idempotent  and nilpotent map to nilpotents.

so here I get only  one ring homorphism   by  the diagram given below

$K_4      \ \  \ \  \   \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \            \mathbb{Z_4}$

$e   \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \rightarrow   \ \ \ \ \ \ \          0$

$ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ 1$

$(a,b,c)  \   \rightarrow       \ \ \ 2$

$\ \ \ \ \  \ \ \  \  \  \ \ \ \ \ \  \ \ \  \  3$

Is its correct ?

Is their any mistake in my solution?

thanks u

Comment: What about trivial homomorphism?

Comment: You are confusing the additive structure and the multiplicative structure in $\Bbb{Z}_2\times\Bbb{Z}_2$: it has no nilpotent elements and all its elements are idempotent. The answer to your question depends on whether you are working with rings with $1$ or not. If you are working with [rngs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rng_(algebra)) there are are some homomorphisms; if you are working with rings with $1$ there are not (or only the trivial homomorphism).

Comment: @RobArthan thanks u

Comment: @ThomasShelby okss